# Ionic AdMob-Plus Plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, admob, ionic4, phaser-framework

i am building a mobile Game with Phaser and Ionic and want to add AdMob.

I installed this plugin:
https://github.com/admob-plus/admob-plus

`cordova plugin add cordova-admob-plus --variable APP_ID_ANDROID=ca-app-pub-xxx~xxx --variable APP_ID_IOS=ca-app-pub-xxx~xxx`

In the page that is using AdMob i added this:

```
declare var admob;
```

Then i can show an ad by using this:

```
admob.banner.show({
id: {
  ios: 'ca-app-pub-xxx~xxx',
 }
});
```

But i need to change the Banner-Size.

Someone know how can i change the size from
"SMART_BANNER" to "BANNER"?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello friend! I would like to know how can you do the build? I am facing the following issue: CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/manel/Documents/ionic_projects/xstories/xstories/platforms/ios/XStories/Plugins/cordova-admob-plus/AMSRewardVideo.swift

Answer (score 1):

First, run `npm uninstall @ionic-native/admob-plus`. This wrapper implementation was never finished and is missing several IBannerRequest options necessary to be used propely.

Instead, declare admob:

```
declare var admob;
```

Then you can reference the Cordova plugin directly. I was able to get it to work by specifying width and height:

```
admob.setDevMode(true);
admob.banner.show({
    id: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716', //iOS test ID
    size: {
        width: 300,
        height: 250
    }
}).then((res) => {
    console.debug('banner show success');
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('banner show failure');
});
```

This allows for the hide method to accept the ID argument it needs to dismiss banner ads properly:

```
admob.banner.hide('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716');
```

API reference for cordova-admob-plus banners can be found here:
https://admob-plus.github.io/docs/show-banner.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this already?

```
admob.banner.show({
id: {
  ios: 'ca-app-pub-xxx~xxx',
},
size: 'BANNER'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my ionic project, what I have done is following.

```
const banner = new this.admob.BannerAd({
       adUnitId: 'ad-unit-id',
       size: AdSizeType.BANNER
     });
await banner.show();
```